# Running a load off a solar panel connected to 2x 12V batteries.

Tags: batteries, switches, relay, solar-cell, 12v

I am having trouble figuring out what relay I should be using for my solar panel set up.

I have a solar panel running to a solar charge controller. I then have the controller running into a relay. The purpose of the relay is to allow the panel to charge one of the 12V batteries while letting the load run off the other 12V battery. I then have a 12V timer switch that is connected to the relay to flip the direction of current from one battery to the other.

I have attached an illustration of my current set up that does not work. When the timer switch activates or deactivates, it does not change what battery is running the system.

I really do apologize for being a total noob, my normal work is with fish :)

If anyone is wondering this is for a Passive Integrated Transponder system used to monitor salmon movement. [image: Current PIT Antenna set up]

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on the relay - part number perhaps?

Comment: A real schematic or at least a link to a datasheet for the relay, or even the relay make and part number, would help in determining why the relay doesn't switch battteries.  Does the relay click when the timer tries to switch it? (some info on the timer would be helpful, as well.)

Comment: This is the timer.

http://www.amazon.com/Neewer%C2%AE-Digital-Power-Programmable-Switch/dp/B00AJGX0JS/ref=pd_sim_hi_4?ie=UTF8&refRID=04MHCWX7B9P09XH3SD4S

Relay webpage with schematic link

http://www.newark.com/finder/56-34-9-012-0000/relay-4pco-12vdc/dp/23M9163

Answer (score 2):

There should be no need to switch the batteries around as you describe.

It seems to be widely recommended that, in a system like this, the two batteries be connected in parallel, and to both the charging source and the load.  When the solar panel is producing more current than the load needs, the excess current will charge the batteries.  When the solar panel is producing less current than the load requires, the extra current will come from the batteries.  The battery charge/discharge "switching" occurs automatically as the current supplied by the solar panels and the current required by the load vary.

Using the batteries this way reduces the number and depth-of-discharge of the charge/discharge cycles of the batteries and so should increase the battery life.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should clarify that the reason I am hoping to have this system is that having the charge controller directly charging the batteries in parallel makes a lot of noise in the system and therefore the antenna does not work as well. By running it off only a battery, the noise is reduced and our read range is increased.

Comment: OK, if you have a Darn Good Reason :-)

Comment: Peter's advice here is very good. If you have a noise problem, it might be caused by the Solar Charge Controller using  a regulation technique called PWM. This noise can be controlled with a filter, and the filter solution would be much less headache than the switching relay. The filter can be just a low value resistor and capacitor (or maybe a coil too).